# C# attribute name abbreviation

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

How is it possible that C# attributes have "Attribute" in their name (e.g. `DataMemberAttribute`) but are initialized without this suffix? e.g.:

```
[DataMember]
private int i;
```

Comment: I'd remark that the question is **HOW** is it possible, was no answered yet. but I believe that it searches using reflection `X OR X + "Attribute"` for names.

Comment: @serhio according to Anton Gogolev it is a shortcut provided by the compiler. This is sufficient for me as answer (if it's correct). And it works with custom attributes too.

Comment: Personally for me is not very clear what kind of "shortcut" can provide a compiler.

Comment: @serhio - less of a name to carry around perhaps? It does seem a bit inconsistent (does the compiler remove "class" from a class name suffix?), but at least it makes sense.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664616(VS.71).aspx),

> By convention, attribute classes are named with a suffix of `Attribute`. An *attribute-name* of the form *type-name* may either include or omit this suffix.

This is a shortcut provided by the C# compiler and by no means a CLR feature. Another example of special treatment of attributes by the compiler is an [ObsoleteAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx) attribute: this one forces a *compiler* to issue a warning/error, but it has no special meaning for the CLR.

As for how attributes are resolved, see the link above. To sum it up:

> If an attribute class is found both with and without this suffix, an ambiguity is present, and a compile-time error results. If the `attribute-name` is spelled such that its right-most identifier is a [verbatim identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(VS.71).aspx), then only an attribute without a suffix is matched, thus enabling such an ambiguity to be resolved.

A "verbatim identifier" is an identifier with an `@` prefix.

Continuing with MSDN:

```
using System;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class X: Attribute
{}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class XAttribute: Attribute
{}

[X]                  // Error: ambiguity
class Class1 {}

[XAttribute]         // Refers to XAttribute
class Class2 {}

[@X]                  // Refers to X
class Class3 {}

[@XAttribute]         // Refers to XAttribute
class Class4 {}
```

> The attribute `[X]` is ambiguous, since it could refer to either `X` or `XAttribute`. Using a verbatim identifier allows the exact intent to be specified in such rare cases. The attribute `[XAttribute]` is not ambiguous (although it would be if there was an attribute class named `XAttributeAttribute`!). If the declaration for class `X` is removed, then both attributes refer to the attribute class named `XAttribute`, as follows:

```
using System;
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class XAttribute: Attribute
{}

[X]                  // Refers to XAttribute
class Class1 {}

[XAttribute]         // Refers to XAttribute
class Class2 {}

[@X]                  // Error: no attribute named "X"
class Class3 {}
```

Answer (score 7):

this is the same thing. `[XAttribute] == [X]`

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48zeb25s%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> By convention, all attribute names end
>   with the word "***Attribute***" to
>   distinguish them from other items in
>   the .NET Framework. However, you do
>   not need to specify the attribute
>   suffix when using attributes in code.
>   For example, `[DllImport]` is equivalent
>   to `[DllImportAttribute]`, but **`DllImportAttribute`** is the attribute's
>   actual name in the .NET Framework.

we can read also:

> If an attribute class is found both
>   with and without this suffix, an
>   ambiguity is present, and a
>   compile-time error results. If the
>   attribute-name is spelled such that
>   its right-most identifier is a
>   verbatim identifier, then only an attribute without a
>   suffix is matched, thus enabling such
>   an ambiguity to be resolved:

```
using System;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class X: Attribute
{}
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class XAttribute: Attribute
{}
[X]                  // Error: ambiguity
class Class1 {}
[XAttribute]         // Refers to XAttribute
class Class2 {}
[@X]                  // Refers to X
class Class3 {}
[@XAttribute]         // Refers to XAttribute
class Class4 {}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a convention in the C#-compiler. Like it says on the [MSDN-page on 'Using Attributes'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48zeb25s(VS.71).aspx):

> By convention, all attribute names end
>   with the word "Attribute" to
>   distinguish them from other items in
>   the .NET Framework. However, you do
>   not need to specify the attribute
>   suffix when using attributes in code.
>   For example, *[DllImport*] is equivalent
>   to *[DllImportAttribute]*, but
>   **DllImportAttribute** is the attribute's
>   actual name in the .NET Framework.

It works [the same way in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163802.aspx).

Comment: You said that this is a convention in .NET Framework, so why you should distinguish between C# and VB.NET?